# On Android: How can I rescan an entire folder to watch for changes in .nomedia

Tags: android, android-sdcard

So my app downloads images at the users' request from an online source.  Through a button in the activity, the user can choose to hide or show the images in the gallery.  This is easy enough, I just add or remove a .nomedia file as needed.  However, I want to rescan media every time so that the change is instant, and requires no further user interaction.

After each image is downloaded, I am using the method at http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg24164.html to scan the specific image into the library.  That works great for one image, but when the .nomedia file is added, I really need to be able to scan a whole directory.

I have considered calling the MediaScannerNotifier on each image in the directory, but that just seems clumsy and lazy.

Advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found it at http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c1a385226f3df482.

It is a one-liner:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse
("file://"
+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: Suprisingly, this doesn't notice change in folder with changed .nomedia, tested on Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard
```

This command can be used to update the SD Card without rebooting the device

Answer (score -1):

One can also invoke from the shell:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard
```

Comment: Hard-coded sdcard path, it's not going to work on some devices.