# Android content resolver doesn't find new images

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-mediascanner

the content provider `MediaStore.Images.Media` doesn't find the new images that has been created to runtime. I have to restart the emulator.
Have you got any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410807/on-android-how-can-i-rescan-an-entire-folder-to-watch-for-changes-in-nomedia/3412985#3412985

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember exact details but I think you have to use MediaScanner after you have added the images