# Android Downloadmanager limit

Tags: android, download, limit, android-mediascanner, android-download-manager

I use the Android downloadmanager (above 2.3) for downloading many small files with different file extension (png,jpg,mov).
After downloading 30000 images the android.process.media stop working and there isn't any exception message.
The Downloaddir is /mnt/sd/Android/com.app.example/chache/files

I also preventing mediascanning for the downloaddir by using .nomedia files.
http://android2know.blogspot.co.at/2013/01/create-nomedia-file.html
[Preventing Media Scanner from Scanning JPGs Downloaded with the DownloadManager on Android? (Developer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391670/preventing-media-scanner-from-scanning-jpgs-downloaded-with-the-downloadmanager)

Is the Android Downloadmanager not responsive for more than 40000 files?
Should I write my own Downloadmanager in this case?

regards sebi

Comment: why not just do it in batches?

Comment: what did you mean? 
i forgot to mentioned that
the download url's came from a cpp core, these have to be downloaded before the programm starts...

Comment: Can you just create a list of files you want to download, and then download just the first say 20000 images. Then save your state, clear the cache, or whatever you have to do, and then download the next 20000. Just keep doing that until you download all the files?